# How to test System.out.println(); by mocking

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

hello I have to practice how to use Mockito can someone please tell me how do we use mock objects to test the console based output testing for example

```
Random rand = new Random();
int number = 1+rand.nextInt(100);              // random number 1 to 100
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i=1; i<=10; i++){                     // for loop from 1 to 10
    System.out.println(" guess "+i+ ":");``
    int guess = scan.nextInt();
    //if guess is greater than number entered 
    if(guess>number)
        System.out.println("Clue: lower");
    //if guess is less than number entered 
    else if (guess<number )
        System.out.println("lue: Higher");
    //if guess is equal than number entered 
    else if(guess==number) {
        System.out.println("Correct answer after only "+ i + " guesses – Excellent!");
        scan.close();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}

System.out.println("you lost" + number);
scan.close();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Best way to get familiar with Mockito (or anything) is by trying to use it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [stackoverflow is not your programming 101 teacher](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198358/stackoverflow-is-not-your-programming-101-teacher). Please check out the Mockito tutorials and ask a specific question on using Mockito.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off - the call to System.exit() will break your test.

Second - not a good idea to mock the `System` class. It makes more sense to redirect System.out to a fake or stub.

Third - Reading stuff from System.in will be tricky to do from test as well.

Apart from that: I've taken the liberty to reduce the code for readability:

```
public class WritesOut {

    public static void doIt() {
           System.out.println("did it!");
    }

}
```

Test should test if Line was printed to System.out:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.junit.Test;

public class WritesOutTestUsingStub {

    @Test
    public void testDoIt() throws Exception {
        //Redirect System.out to buffer
        ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(bo));
        MockOut.doIt();
        bo.flush();
        String allWrittenLines = new String(bo.toByteArray()); 
        assertTrue(allWrittenLines.contains("did it!"));
    }

}
```

Comment: *Second - no way to mock System classes. But you can redirect.*

Sorry this is incorrect, you CAN set the System.out to a mock class. It would be dumb, but you could do it.
You can also mock [System with PowerPock](http://ihaztehcodez.michael-lloyd-lee.me.uk/2009/10/mocking-system-classes.html). I would not, but you can.

Comment: Also not very good when test are multi-treaded. If other threads want to print 1. you will loose the output of those threads 2. your test may/will break

Comment: Good point @Brice, you would be better off injected a PrinterStream and passing System.out on live, and an in-memory version in test (or separating output from logic)

Answer (score 2):

I would NOT use mockito in order to test this. I'd set the System.out (via [System.setOut](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream))) to a [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) backed PrintStream and check that.

Also you want rid of that System.exit if you want to unit test.

The two things I would look at mocking are the [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) and the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). I'd also look at separating logic from display. You don't really care WHAT gets outputted, but rather the logic understands that with input X you get output Y.

Why? If you mock the System.out (which you could do via System.setOut) you would end up showing that you can write mock verification but little else. The test code would end up being very brittle and very hard to follow.
By instead using ByteArrayOutputStream you can get the output in a significantly simplified way.

The Random and Scanner are external systems that are much simpler to [stub out](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) and will not leave you with quite so brittle code.

However as I said I would separate game logic from user input. For example I'd have an class that understood the game.

```
class Game
   // implementation
   Game(int startingNumber, int attemptsAllowed);

   public {WON,HIGHER,LOWER,LOST} go(int guess) { ... }
}
```

This object can then be tested easily and in complete isolation from the (harder to test) user interface.

When you want to test the user interface you can mock this object to ensure it always returns what you want it too return.

Comment: can you discribe how can i use mokito to do testing on Scanner and Random? my goal is to learn mokito framework and this is just a random task i chose. thanks in advance

Comment: Learning mockito by "random tasks" does not feel to me like a good way to go about it. What tests would you write for this class? Why might you want to mock (or stub) Random and Scanner?