# how can I write a test for void methods with junit in Java especially they do not return a value?

Tags: java, junit

I have here a simple program to resolve hostname to ip address and vice versa and do not have any idea ,how can I test these two void methods with junit , as long they don't return any values.
I need help with junit test , because my void methods don't return any thing.

```
    /*
 * inside this interface we have two function,that 
 * resolve ip to host-addr and vice versa
 */
public interface DnsFunctions {

    public void resolveHostToIp();

    public void resolveIpToHost();
}
```

and here ist the main code for the Dns resolver where the void methods are invoked inside the switch case :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class DnsResolver implements DnsFunctions {

    static BufferedReader br;
    static DnsFunctions df = new DnsResolver();
    static boolean status = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Welcome to DNS-resolver page :");
        sb.append("\n*select (1) to resolve Hostname to IP-Address");
        sb.append("\n*select (2) to get the Host name from inputed IP-Address");
        sb.append("\n*select (3) for EXIT");

        System.out.println(sb);

        /*
         * depending on the inputted value from user /1-2 or 3/ the suitable function
         * will be called
         */

        while (status) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            int inputedValue = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            switch (inputedValue) {

            case 1:

                df.resolveHostToIp();
                status = true;
                break;

            case 2:
                df.resolveIpToHost();
                status = true;
                break;

            case 3:
                status = false;
                System.out.println("GoodBye :)");
                break;

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    /*
     * 
     * @parameter value
     */
    public void resolveHostToIp() {
        try {
            System.out.println("\n Enter Hostname:");
            String hostName = br.readLine();

            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(hostName);
            System.out.println("Hostname :" + address.getHostName());
            System.out.println("IP:" + address.getHostAddress());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR :(" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    /*
     * @parameter value
     */
    public void resolveIpToHost() {
        try {
            System.out.println("\n Enter IP address");
            String ip_add = br.readLine();
            InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByName(ip_add);
            System.out.println("IP: " + ip_add);
            System.out.println("Host Name: " + ia.getHostName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR :(" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test System.out.println(); by mocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569920/how-to-test-system-out-println-by-mocking)

Comment: @mentallurg: The only side-effect those methods produce is writing to `System.out.println`.  Redirecting `System.out` would allow one to unit test them.

Comment: @David: In *this* particular implementation - yes. But there can be other implementations.

Comment: @sami htw: Perhaps this is cause to re-think the interface/implementation?  Which often happens when trying to write unit tests.

Comment: @sami htw: Is this your *final* implementation of the interface? Or do you plan that these methods will change some fields or some other objects?

Comment: @David's solution looks good to me. If the interface is in your codebase, perhaps you could change it to throw the checked exceptions, rather than swallowing them and test for that?

Comment: **Why** are these methods `void`?  Would it not make more sense **and** make them easier to test if they returned the values that they fetch?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the only observable effect produced by these methods is that they write to `System.out`.  Nothing more.  And the interface doesn't indicate that in any way.

One option to test the *implementation* would be to [redirect and observe `System.out`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569920/how-to-test-system-out-println-by-mocking).  If, however, there's ever a different implementation which *doesn't* write to `System.out` then that would fail the test.  It'll work if you're reluctant to change the code, but has its downsides as well.

If on the other hand you can change the code, then you can make the methods more testable by having them *return* their values instead of *printing* their values.  Then in the `main()` method you would print the returned values.

The benefit here becomes cleaner testability by separating the concern of *producing* the value from the concern of *outputting* the value.  They're two different things and should be handled separately, even if both are small and simple.

From a purist unit testing perspective, you'd likely also want to encapsulate the dependency on the static methods in `InetAddress`, likely by wrapping it in a mockable object and injecting a mock for the test.

It approaches an interesting problem though, because once both of these dependencies are removed then the methods effectively don't *do* anything and the value of testing them in the first place quickly approaches zero.  They'd just be a pass-through to the mock that's being injected, nothing more.

For the immediate purpose, I'd recommend removing the `System.out` dependency and keeping that solely in the `main()` method, having the methods return their values.  And then re-classifying your unit tests as "integration tests" with a known dependency on `InetAddress`.

Comment: Arguably this `DnsFunctions` interface _is exactly_ that wrapper that you mentioned.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-: Possibly, but then the necessity of unit testing it becomes very low.  When all a method does is pass through to a dependency and contains no logic, the ratio of effort to reward for grasping at 100% code coverage becomes a point worth considering.

Comment: Entirely agreed, but it seems that this is part of an exercise teaching OP how to perform unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

This is (almost) untestable with jUnit. And pretty useless also, when we look into the implemention.

The main blocker: It's a unit test so we don't want to invoke the real `getByName` method on `InetAdress`. We'd have to mock it. But it's a static method and jUnit can't mock that.

The challenges: we'd have to replace `System.out` and `System.in` by methods where we can pass our test data (into the `System.in`) and assert the output (from the mocked `System.out`).

The challenges are solvable, the static method problem requires rewriting your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock `InetAddress.getByName(ip_add);` call and then add a check like - `assertEquals("StringThatShouldComeUpOnConsole", outContent.toString());`

Comment: according to the challenge we can only use junit with testing , I think it is testable when we put the results of each methods inside an ArrayList and compare the the elements in each index with the expected ones.